# Playing music while windows 8 store app is in the background

Tags: windows-runtime, media-player, background-audio

so I tried a few different approaches, and here is where I am:

I setup the MediaElement in the App.xaml using the method shown in this thread ([Global MediaElement that continues playing after navigating to other page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935107/global-mediaelement-that-continues-playing-after-navigating-to-other-page)). It works great to keep music playing when switching panes...

The way I setup the player handlers was to add all the methods (such as Play, Pause, next track, etc) to the LayoutAware page. This way I can control the player from any View. It works great when the app is in focus

If I leave the original view that played the music, and switch to another app, it keeps playing in the background, which is what I want

However, if I first change to a different view, and then move the app to the background, it stops!

It only does this when I navigate away from the panel that first started playing the music.

For example, if I do this:

```
1. launch the app

2. select a track (launches NowPlaying View)

3. Play the track and leave it on that same view

4. Navigate to a different app or the desktop, leaving the app running in the background
```

The app continues playing music.

If I then:

```
5. Navigate back to the app

6. click "Back" to select a different track

7. navigate to a different app or the desktop leaving the app running in the background
```

the music stops!

Anyone have any ideas why this would happen? please let me know if you need more clarification about how I've set this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops this was entirely user error.

I added the handlers for the MediaControl events in the page load, but was removing then OnNavigatedFrom.

I moved the unregister code to the Unloaded event, and now they remain in place so that the music can keep playing!

So in summary: make sure you have your MediaControl event handlers in place and in scope to keep music playing in the background!